# store result of sql request in a variable php

Tags: php, mysql

With a `POST` request, I get the name of someone that I want to link with its id the mySQL database. For that, I create a query as you can see below and I need to put the result (a simple number) into a variable to use it for other queries.

I know that I could make joints with SQL but I'm trying to do it this way.

```
$owner = $_POST['owner'];

$queryUser = "SELECT id FROM collections WHERE name = '$owner'";
$idUser = $mysqli->query($queryUser) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
```

With this code, I can't use `$idUser`because it appears as an 0, a 1 (recogniezd as an array?) or nothing  when I try to write it somewhere in my database. I tried to use the `intval()` function with no results...

Any help?

Comment: Remember to fetch the result ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch result from query:

```
$res = $mysqli->query($queryUser) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
$idUser = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

so your id will be $idUser['id']

Comment: I used the `fetch_assoc()` but I didn't realize that I'll have to use `$idUser['id']` instead of `$idUser`. Many thanks!

Comment: Actually, the fetch displays the good value of the id with an `echo` but I still got a 0 in my database...

Comment: You are selecting id from database, and your result id is in $idUser['id']. Please clarify what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fetch_array` method which fetches the result as an associative array

```
$query = $mysqli->query($queryUser) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

$row = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo $row['id']
```